# Maximize and minimize the JInternalFrame

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have a Jframe which has 3 jInteralFrame. 
Now i fix a maximize,minimize and close button using properties. Close operation be perform correctly. Maximize,Minimize, Restore buttons are not working. So, How to resize, maximize and minimize each internal frame separately using properties.

Answer (score 3):

```
    jInteralFrame.setMaximizable(true); // maximize
    jInteralFrame.setIconifiable(true); // set minimize
    jInteralFrame.setClosable(true); // set closed
    jInteralFrame.setResizable(true); // set resizable
```